# Angular 2 shared service variables return undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to get a value from a shared service that is set by navMenu.component and used by tab.component. I have the feeling it is shared properly but by the time tab.component gets the value it is too late. I tried to use the Elvis operator but got a pare error.

Starting app.component.html

```
<div>
    <div class="outer">

            <nav-menu [gwLinkID]="gwLinkID"  [psnlUID]="psnlUID"  [ntName]="ntName"></nav-menu>


        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <div class="container">  
               <tab></tab>
            </div>
</div>
```

values for the shared service  are set by navMenu.component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'nav-menu',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'navMenu.component.html'
})

export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit {

    tabs: INavMenuTabs[];

    @Input() gwLinkID: number;
    @Input() psnlUID: string;
    @Input() ntName: string;
    pageTitle: any[];
    title: string;
    titleID: number;
    appParams: IAppParams;
    errorMessage: string;
    linkData: any;
    constructor(private _appParams: AppParamasService, private _navMenuService: NavMenuService) {
//    this.gwLinkID = this._appParams.LinkID;
    console.log('inside navMenu.component constructor ' + this._appParams.GetLinkName);


}

getTabs() {
    this._navMenuService.getTabs(this._appParams.LinkID, 'ciiw')
        .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.tabs = data.result
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error),
        this.appParams = this._appParams.GetParams();
    console.log('inside navMenu.component method getTabs ' + this._appParams.GetLinkName);
}
ngOnInit(): void {

    this._navMenuService.getLinkName(this.gwLinkID)
        .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.titleID = data.result.LinkID;
            this._appParams.SetLinkID = data.result.LinkID;
            this.title = data.result.LinkName;
            this._appParams.SetLinkName = this.title;
            this._appParams.SetParams(this.psnlUID, this.ntName, this.gwLinkID);
            this.getTabs(); // call the tabs-method here, data is available here!
        });
    console.log('inside navMenu.component method ngOnInit ' + this._appParams.GetLinkName);
    }

}
```

shared service

```
@Injectable()

export class AppParamasService {

    params: IAppParams;
    constructor() {

    }

    private _linkName: string;
    get GetLinkName(): string {
        return this._linkName;
    }
    set SetLinkName(value: string) {
        this._linkName = value;
    }


}
```

shared service methods are consumed by tab.component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tab',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'tab.component.html'
})
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {

    linkName: string;
    appParams: IAppParams;
   constructor(private _appParams: AppParamasService) {

    console.log('inside tab.component constructor ' + this._appParams.GetLinkName);

}

CheckValue()
{
   console.log('inside tab.component CheckValue ' + this._appParams.GetLinkName);
}
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.linkName = this._appParams.GetLinkName;
    console.log('inside tab.component ngOnInt ' + this._appParams.GetLinkName);


}
}
```

tab.component.html

```
<div class="team">
       <h3 *ngIf="linkName">{{linkName}}</h3>
</div>
```

one thing to note if i change the constructor inside navMenu.component.ts to

> constructor(private _appParams: AppParamasService, private
>   _navMenuService: NavMenuService) {
>
> ```
>     this._appParams.SetLinkName = 'Test';
>
> }
> ```

everything works and the value is available for tab.component.ts, so it is an issue with at what stage values are available to other copomnents

output from console logs

- inside navMenu.component constructor undefined
- inside tab.component constructor undefined
- inside navMenu.component method ngOnInit undefined
- inside tab.component ngOnInt undefined
- inside navMenu.component method getTabs Financial Planning Reports
  Admin

Comment: Just a note, "?." is *not* the Elvis operator, it is the safe navigation operator.

Comment: Could you try to add console log to `set SetLikName(value: string) {this._linkName = value; console.log(this._linkName)}`. Does it give a value?

Comment: @Matt: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/elvis-operator-in-angular-2.0

Comment: @AJT_82, That blogger guy mixed it up. You'll find the correct definition of both operators in every official documentation of languages that support them:  http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_elvis_operator , http://fantom.org/doc/docLang/Expressions , last but not least: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator

Comment: thanks guys, but this does not resolve my issue. I discovered one thing edited the above code. If I hard code the value inside the constructor of navMenu.componenet.ts          this._appParams.SetLinkName = 'Test';
it works and the value is available for tab.component.ts.

Comment: @rgoal, look at my comment above where I ask you to console log. Well, now you have narrowed down the issue somewhat at least. This is why it's important to console.log like crazy in the code so that you know EXACTLY where data gets lost... Just a thought for the future. Debug your code so you can narrow it down ;)

Comment: @AJT Already did ;) added the results from the console in the above code. the value gets lost after   getTabs method inside navMenu.component.ts finish executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `nav component` and `tab component` are initialized at the same time, it means that when `OnInit` in the `tab component` is executed, the value from the shared service has not yet gotten a value to emit to the `tab component`. This can be solved to make the shared service use `Subjects` instead, so that tab component will subscribe to the value.

So your service should look something like this:

```
private linkNameSource = new Subject<any>();
linkNameValue$ = this.linkNameSource.asObservable();

  linkNameReceived(linkName) {
    //emit linkName, your tab component will subscribe to this value in constructor
    this.linkNameSource.next(linkName)
  }
```

and in your `nav component`, change this:

```
this._appParams.SetLinkName = this.title;
```

to the following (where we push the value to your shared service) and that will emit the value to your `tab component`, which is subscribing to the value.

```
this._appParams.linkNameReceived(this.title)
```

Then in your tab component add the following:

```
// declare your local variable
linkName;

constructor(private _appParams: AppParamasService) {
  // subscribe to the value from the shared service
  this._appParams.linkNameValue.subscribe(linkName => {
    this.linkName = linkName;
  }
}
```

This should clear things up! Please refer to this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) in angular.io where this same example I have provided for you is explained with more details than I have provided.

Comment: Thanks AJT, sorry for the typo it is LinkName not LinkNam. I updated the code above. the issue still remain . I even put it in a variable called title and displayed it in navMeu.htlm just to see it, and the value showed up, so this line this._appParams.SetLikName = data.result.LinkNam; is working . the value is not persistent when it s retrieved to be used by another control.

Comment: Okay, well you have so much code in your post, so it's really hard to even understand, at least for me I'm having difficulties reading all that code :D Don't even know in which order nav component and tab component is executed. Are they loaded at same time? Is there a navigation somewhere, or how is the app built?

Comment: And have you console logged all the way, at what point exactly is the data still intact and exactly where is it lost?

Comment: edited my code by removing code that is not related.. yes all are loaded at the same time. see app.compoenet.html. the issue is with <tab><tab/>. I can pass it title as an input butt realy dont want to do that. is the above code clearer ? Yes, i set consol log in the navMenu.component.ts and was able to confirm the value is set. also did the same thing in tab.component which it prints undefined

Comment: Great! You are welcome. Took some time, but you finally got a solution :D

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the optional operator without a following expression like

```
 {{foo?.bar}}
```

Its purpose is to prevent access violations to properties when the parent is `undefined` or `null`. In your example you just have a simple object which would be printed e.g. as `null` or `undefined`.

Perhaps you want the complete `h3` not to be rendered if the link is undefined. Something like this

```
 <h3 *ngIf="linkName">{{linkName}}</h3>
```

Comment: I tried that  and I don't  get the value, which does not resolve my issue. so why my linkName is undefined ? It was set to a value by navMenu.component.ts

Comment: You should check your code for typos, especially case-related. Take a  look at these: "GetlinkName" and "SetLikName". One missing character and different case for the "L". Besides, when using ``get`` and ``set``, you would omit the "set" prefix. It is just "set linkName(value:string) {...}"